# A more appropriate way to use RuntimeTools`Profile

Tags: undocumented, debugging

There's a powerful tool call `` RuntimeTools`Profile ``, but it's hard to use.

I must turn on `Debug` mode, then use `` RuntimeTools`Profile ``, it'll open a new `Notebook`, then I need to copy the `Cell` and close the notebook, then turn off `Debug` mode if necessary.

That's too complicated!

Now I want a new funcion `Profile` to finish all the things above.

Comment: What do you call ``RuntimeTools`Profile`` on?

Comment: Impossible I think..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**

Here's a new version that doesn't require a stylesheet:

```
SetAttributes[profile, HoldAll]

profile[expr_] /; !TrueQ@$Once := Module[{eval=EvaluationNotebook[]},
    $Once = True;
    SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,"DebuggerSettings"->{"DebuggerEnabled"->True}];

    SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell];
    SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[eval]
]

profile[expr_] := Module[{nb},
    Block[{NotebookCreate = (nb = CreateDocument[{}, Visible->False])&},
        Internal`WithLocalSettings[
            $Once =.,

            RuntimeTools`Profile[expr],

            CellPrint @ NotebookImport[nb, "Text"->"Cell"];
            NotebookClose[nb];
            SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,"DebuggerSettings"->{"DebuggerEnabled"->False}]
        ]
    ]
]
```

And here it is in action:

```
profile[
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 1;
    f[n_] := f[n-1] + f[n-2];
    f[5]
]
```

> `Calls   Time    Evaluation
>   7   0.000242    f[n_]
>   7   0.000212    f[n-1]+f[n-2]
>   7   0.000138    f[n-1]
>   1   0.000123    f[0]=1;f[1]=1;f[n_]:=f[Plus[<<2>>]]+f[Plus[<<2>>]];f[5]
>   1   0.0001  f[5]
>   7   0.00006 f[n-2]
>   1   0.000012    f[n_]:=f[n-1]+f[n-2]`
>
> 8

**Old version**

You can programmatically change the debug status by using:

```
SetOptions[
    $FrontEnd,
    "DebuggerSettings"->{"DebuggerEnabled"->True}
]
```

However, `` RuntimeTools`Profile `` is expecting the debug status to be set at the beginning of the evaluation, so toggling the debug status needs to happen before evaluation starts. This makes it difficult to create a function that toggles the debug status, and then runs `` RuntimeTools`Profile ``.

My approach for solving this conundrum is to create a new style ("DebugInput") that toggles the debug status as part of the cell prolog. This occurs early enough that `` RuntimeTools`Profile `` will recognize that change in status. In order to make it easy to use this new style, I've added [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) so that typing <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the start of the cell will toggle between the "Input" and the "DebugInput" styles.

Here is some code to use a stylesheet with the new style:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions->Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Input"],
            StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"DebugInput"}
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["DebugInput", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Input"]],
            StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"Input"},
            CellProlog :> SetOptions[
                $FrontEnd,
     "DebuggerSettings"->{"DebuggerEnabled"->True}
    ],
    CellEpilog :> SetOptions[
     $FrontEnd,
                "DebuggerSettings"->{"DebuggerEnabled"->False}
            ]
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

The next problem is that `` RuntimeTools`Profile `` uses [`NotebookCreate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookCreate) instead of [`CreateDocument`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDocument). This means that notebook options like `Visible->False` can't be used to hide the notebook. I work around this issue by blocking `NotebookCreate` to a `CreateDocument` call with the needed option. Here is the code for a function `profile` that runs `` RuntimeTools`Profile `` and puts the output in the notebook:

```
SetAttributes[profile,HoldFirst];

profile[expr_] := Module[{nb, style},
    style = MatchQ[
        "Style"/.Developer`CellInformation[EvaluationCell[]],
        "DebugInput"
    ];
    If[!style, Message[profile::style]];
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        Null,
        Block[{NotebookCreate = (nb = CreateDocument[{}, Visible->False])&},
            RuntimeTools`Profile[expr]
        ],
        CellPrint @ NotebookImport[nb, "Text"->"Cell"]
    ] /; style
]

profile::style = "Cell style must be \"DebugInput\". Use \[TabKey] at start of cell to change style";
```

Here is `profile` in action. The following code is in an ordinary "Input" cell:

```
profile[
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 1;
    f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2];
    f[6]
]
```

> During evaluation of In[4]:= profile::style: Cell style must be "DebugInput". Use \[TabKey] at start of cell to change style
>
> profile[f[0] = 1; f[1] = 1; f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]; f[6]]

Notice the instruction to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the start of the cell to change the cell style. After doing so, we get:

```
profile[
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 1;
    f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2];
    f[6]
]
```

> `Calls   Time    Evaluation
>   12  0.000689    f[n_]
>   12  0.000619    f[n-1]+f[n-2]
>   12  0.000407    f[n-1]
>   1   0.000258    f[0]=1;f[1]=1;f[n_]:=f[Plus[<<2>>]]+f[Plus[<<2>>]];f[6]
>   1   0.000222    f[6]
>   12  0.000187    f[n-2]
>   25  0.000019    f[0]
>   28  0.000015    f
>   1   0.000015    f[n_]:=f[n-1]+f[n-2]`
>
> 13

Comment: Nice answer. I find it interesting that the rule for f[1] is never called.

Comment: We arrive Rome from Berlin in New York transit. :)

Comment: For some reason both versions return only number of evaluations on my system (*Mathematica* 11.2.0 on Win7 x64). The new version also returns empty table `Calls|Time|Evaluation`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Is it possible you didn’t set the attributes of profile to HoldFirst or HoldAll?

Comment: As Alexey I only get an empty table. I'm also in Win7 and have tried Mathematica 10.4.1, 11.0.1, 11.1.1 and 11.2.0 ... Is there some setting that needs to be done before ``RuntimeTools`Profile`` will work? For me the manual use of ``RuntimeTools`Profile`` will also only return an empty table...

Comment: @CarlWoll I just checked again: `profile` (the new version) is `HoldAll` but prints empty table.

Comment: I also get the empty table Calls|Time|Evaluation. Is there a patch for this behavior in 11.3?

Comment: @CarlWoll This is great, but is it possible to generalise this to work with code inside a package as well? (see my question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187368/profiling-a-package/187610#187610)

Comment: Great tool! Just used this to make my function 100 times faster (I guess Expectation was not meant to be called in a loop)