# Is it possible to profile Wolfram Language code without Workbench?

Tags: debugging

Are there any tools built into the latest version of Mathematica that would allow a user to run a profiler against packages? I have read [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187368/profiling-a-package), but there have been two releases since that question was asked, and I am hoping that the latest version of Mathematica obviates the need for installing a JRE and Eclipse, and other heavy software.

Comment: Are you aware of this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Performance tuning in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica)

Comment: If you run `PacletInstall["Instrumentation"]` in 12.1, it will install a paclet that has both profiling and coverage functionality. This was created by [brenton](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/63281/brenton) who also wrote the [linter](https://github.com/WolframResearch/codeinspector/). It's still a bit rough around the edges, and the documentation is hard to find. Enter `Instrumentation/tutorial/ProfileTutorial` manually in the address bar (or `Instrumentation/tutorial/CoverageTutorial` for the coverage tool).

Comment: I am using the coverage tools, and I am quite happy with them. I have not used the profiling tools seriously (I tried them, but I cannot comment on the accuracy of results)

Comment: I didn't want to post a full answer. I'll leave that to Brenton to do in the duplicate target when he thinks that the package is sufficiently mature. But at this point the availability of this paclet is no secret. Just keep in mind that at least in the recent past, the package was changing fairly quickly, and I needed to keep adapting my code.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think your comment about `Instrumentation` paclet deserves much more visibility. Will you consider making it an answer?

Comment: @Szabolcs unfortunately documentations seems to have gone in recent releases