# Profiling in Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, debugging

This is meant as a broad question, because I couldn't find such a discussion on this topic (the questions I found are very old and basic, e.g. the [most popular one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/profiling-from-mathematica) only shows where to find Mathematica's profiler).

Sorry if I missed something, or if it is too general.

## How do you profile your Mathematica code?

By this I mean say you have some large code, and you want to know how long each step takes, in order to find out what to optimise for example.

I'm talking specifically about the time taken, as opposed to e.g. memory used or finding bugs.

### Do you use Mathematica's

```
    RuntimeTools`Profile
```

either within Workbench (which seems to be necessary if the code you're profiling is in a package, [see this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187368/profiling-a-package)) or directly in the notebook (in which case [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161421/16048) is a nice way to avoid having to manually set the notebook in debug mode, close the newly opened notebook and unset the debug mode)?

If so, how do you know whether the timings are accurate?

Are there certain things it fails at and others that are more accurate?

What are common pitfalls?

Is this documented anywhere?(the [official](https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp) documentation is rather limited)

Any general advice from an experienced user?

### Or do you use your own/a third party's code?

In which case, what is it, and how do you recommend using it?

Comment: Mostly, I profile with  `AbsoluteTiming` or `RepeatedTiming` and `Print`; I know, not very professional...