# Profiling - workarounds/fixes for unreliable RuntimeTools`Profile? Update added Clue

Tags: performance-tuning, workbench, debugging

[MMA 11.0.1.0 Win 10 64-bit]

I have tried using RuntimeTools`Profile manually and the most useful profile[] function provided by @Carl-Woll in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161397/a-more-appropriate-way-to-use-runtimetoolsprofile/161421#161421).

Sadly, neither work reliably and the culprit seems to be the Debugger and Profile; as stated by many commenters to @Carl-Woll's answer, there is often no profile table content.

After a fresh start of MMA, this trivial example produced the following results in six sequential attempts.

```
a = 11;
b = 13;
c = 17;
h[a_, b_, c_] := a^2 + b2^2 + c^2;
RuntimeTools`Profile@Do[h[a, b, c], 1000];
```

[image]

I note that like the commenters above 1/3 of the time I receive an empty table, but 1/3 of the time the table had 4 rows... and 1/3 of the time it had 2 rows. I can find no cause for any of this aberrant behaviour, and these results are solidly reproducible.

Is this now a confirmed bug? Are there any workarounds? How can I profile my code reliably?

NB I also have Workbench set up, but something (I guess the size of my data lists ~10^7 elements each... of which there are many) make single stepping in debug mode there impractical too - ~10s per step, so I really don't know how best to approach debugging or profiling. (Yes, I could use smaller data frames, but then I would have to try to characterise the non-linearities, extrapolate...)

** UPDATE **

A clue as to what is wrong is suggested by the following

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := Table[f[n], {n, 1, x}];
Do[
  RuntimeTools`Profile@Do[g[10], {m, 10^i}];
  , {i, 1, 5}];
```

I noted that the longer the run time of the code to be profiled the longer the table became - and for very short run times the table was empty.

Is it simply a bug in the profiler such that code can run too quickly for it to notice any time passing, and does not output the decomposition of the calls with 0 for each, instead outputting nothing?

I love the irony of this: when trying out @Carl-Wolls answer I, like others I expect, tried simple code to profile... the empty tables may be a result of PC speed and code simplicity, the irony being that if code fails on a trivial example, why would one then test it on the real-world example (where it may in fact work!)